# Passing Parameter to SAP query_view_data from flex

Tags: apache-flex, sap-bw

I am new to flex and SAP. I am designing a dashboard in flex. I have retrieved data from SAP query_view_data and I am able to show it in charts. However now I want to pass parameter to SAP web service to retrieve data between two dates. I am trying to this with the following code:

```
protected function adg1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{           
  var IInfoprovider:String="0FIGL_O02";

  var w:Object= new Object();
  var Parameter:Array = new Array();

  w.Name = "VAR_NAME_1";
  w.Value = "OCOMP_CODE";
  Parameter.push(w);

  w = null ;
  w = new Object(); 
  w.Name = "VAR_VALUE_EXT_1";
  w.Value = "1028";
  Parameter.push(w);
  w=null;

  w = new Object(); 
  w.Name = "VAR_NAME_2";
  w.Value = "OCALMONTH";
  Parameter.push(w);
  w=null;

  w = new Object(); 
  w.Name = "VAR_VALUE_LOW_EXT_2";
  w.Value = "01032008";
  Parameter.push(w);
  w=null;

  w = new Object(); 
  w.Name = "VAR_VALUE_HIGH_EXT_2";
  w.Value = "01092008";
  Parameter.push(w);
  w=null;

  var ITParameter:ArrayCollection= new ArrayCollection(Parameter);

  var IQuery:String="ZFIGL_0FIGL_O02_QD008";
  var IViewId:String="";
  Rrw3GetQueryViewDataResult.token = rRW3_GET_QUERY_VIEW_DATA.Rrw3GetQueryViewData(IInfoprovider, IQuery, ITParameter, IViewId);        
}
```

However the whole data is shown in the data grid instead of the filtered data.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Your code makes no sense and key-value pairs aren't done like that.  Plus, where's the actual service call?

Comment: I have used call responder.


<s:CallResponder id="Rrw3GetQueryViewDataResult"/>
  <rrw3_get_query_view_data:RRW3_GET_QUERY_VIEW_DATA id="rRW3_GET_QUERY_VIEW_DATA" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" showBusyCursor="true"/>

Comment: I have two datagrids for the other i tried:
var ITParameter:ArrayCollection= new ArrayCollection();
    ITParameter.addItem({"VAR_NAME_1":"OCOMP_CODE"});
    ITParameter.addItem({"VAR_VALUE_EXT_1":"1007"});
    ITParameter.addItem({"VAR_NAME_2":"0CALMONTH"});
    ITParameter.addItem({"VAR_VALUE_LOW_EXT_2":"01032008"});
    ITParameter.addItem({"VAR_VALUE_HIGH_EXT_2":"01092008"});
Rrw3GetQueryViewDataResult.token = rRW3_GET_QUERY_VIEW_DATA.Rrw3GetQueryViewData(IInfoprovider, IQuery, ITParameter, IViewId);

Comment: Edit the original question.  Code does not belong in comments...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Everything the above code was correct except that i was using column names in w.value. However it should be the SAP variable name for that column. Here is the corrected code:

var w:W3Query= new W3Query();
                w.Name = "VAR_NAME_2";
                w.Value = "ZCOAUTH2";
                Parameter.push(w);
                w = null ;

```
            w = new W3Query(); 
            w.Name = "VAR_VALUE_EXT_2";
            w.Value = "1007";
            Parameter.push(w);
            w=null;

            w = new W3Query(); 
            w.Name = "VAR_NAME_3";
            w.Value = "ZCOAUTH2";
            Parameter.push(w);
            w = null ;

            w = new W3Query(); 
            w.Name = "VAR_VALUE_EXT_3";
            w.Value = "1037";
            Parameter.push(w);
            w=null;

            w = new W3Query(); 
            w.Name = "VAR_NAME_4";
            w.Value = "ZCOAUTH2";
            Parameter.push(w);


            w = null ;
            w = new W3Query(); 
            w.Name = "VAR_VALUE_EXT_4";
            w.Value = "1123";
            Parameter.push(w);



            w=null;
            w = new W3Query(); 


            w.Name = "VAR_NAME_1";
            w.Value = "0I_DAYIN";
            Parameter.push(w);
            w = null ;

            w = new W3Query(); 
            w.Name = "VAR_VALUE_LOW_EXT_1";
            w.Value = df.format( from_date.text);
            Parameter.push(w);
            w=null;

            w = new W3Query(); 
            w.Name = "VAR_VALUE_HIGH_EXT_1";
            w.Value = df.format(to_date.text);
            Parameter.push(w);
            w=null;
```

var ITParameter:ArrayCollection= new ArrayCollection(Parameter);

```
            var IQuery:String="ZFIGL_0FIGL_O02_QDP008";
            var IViewId:String="";

            Rrw3GetQueryViewDataResult.token = rRW3_GET_QUERY_VIEW_DATA.Rrw3GetQueryViewData(IInfoprovider, IQuery, ITParameter, IViewId);
```